# Retrofit2 - Upload image to server give an Internal Server Error as response in android studio

Tags: java, android, node.js, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to send image files from my android app to a back end server. On Postman, images are sent and response code:200 is received.[image]

However, trying to send images from my android app using retrofit, I keep receiving response code:500 Internal Server Error. Here is my code:

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("uploads/addImage")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);
}
```

The NetworkClient

```
public class NetworkClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        if(retrofit == null){
            String BASE_URL = "https://addimage.herokuapp.com/";
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(okHttpClient).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

And then the call

```
private void uploadImage(Uri imageUri){

        File file = new File(imageUri.toString());

        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "image.jpg", requestBody);

        Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofit();
        RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitInterface.uploadImage(body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("UploadImage", "Yeepee!!! = "+response.message());
                }else Log.d("UploadImage", "Response failure = "+response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    // "Connection Timeout";
                    Log.e("UploadImage", "Connection Timeout");
                } else if (t instanceof IOException) {
                    // "Timeout";
                    Log.e("UploadImage", "Timeout");
                } else {
                    //Call was cancelled by user
                    if(call.isCanceled()) {
                        Log.e("UploadImage", "Call was cancelled forcefully");
                    } else {
                        //Generic error handling
                        Log.e("UploadImage", "Network Error :: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I am not sure if it's a server error since images upload successfully from Postman. I am very confused and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can't you export the Request to OkHttp Code with Postman? Or is that what you did?

Comment: Btw 200 OK means that everything worked and 500 Internal server error means that there was e.g. a serveryside exception, as @Saumik Bhattacharjee said.

Answer (score 1):

According to your Postmen screen shot there is no key for image file can you try like below

remove this line

```
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "image.jpg", requestBody);
```

And add this one

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("", "image.jpg", requestBody);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the response @Dulanga. But I did both, the server-side don't seem to require any key.

Answer (score 0):

Generally 500 Internal Server error means there is something wrong in the server, but if the Postman is giving 200 that means the server part is OK, there's something wrong in your code.

try changing this line

```
File file = new File(imageUri.toString());
```

to this

```
File file = new File(imageUri.path);
```

And also make sure that the key name you used is same as the response key name

Comment: The question is why it is working from postman and not from the OP's code.

Comment: Thank @Soumik, but my app is fetching the file accurately since I display it on a bitmap before sending it. I even converted the file to byte[] imageByte and tried sending and still got the same error.                 ```RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageBytes);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "image.jpg", requestBody);```

Comment: Are you taking image from gallery or fetching it from server?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Soumik for your response, but I found the error. You can check my answer above to see what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. I have been able to resolve and it turned out to be a conflict between my request body and what the server was expecting.

For my case, I was sending a different mime-type(a .jpg), where the server developer made the server look for .jpeg and .png.

This was how I got to see the error and resolve the conflict.

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitInterface.uploadImage(body);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
      if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("UploadImage", "Yeepee!!! = "+response.message());
                }else {
                    Log.d("UploadImage", "Response failure = "+response.message());
                    try {
                        Log.d("UploadImage", "Response failure = "+response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d("UploadImage", "IOException = "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                if (t instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    // "Connection Timeout";
                    Log.e("UploadImage", "Connection Timeout");
                } else if (t instanceof IOException) {
                    // "Timeout";
                    Log.e("UploadImage", "Timeout");
                } else {
                    //Call was cancelled by user
                    if(call.isCanceled()) {
                        Log.e("UploadImage", "Call was cancelled forcefully");
                    } else {
                        //Generic error handling
                        Log.e("UploadImage", "Network Error :: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The `response.errorBody().string()` got the error message from the server and I was able to resolve the conflict.